# Google Maps custom markers with GWT

Tags: google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3

currently I'm struggling with custom markers for Google Maps (I am using [branflakes GWT-Maps-V3-Api](https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api)).

I want to:

- identify each marker (write some content into the marker, e.g. 1, 2, 3, ...)
- make the markers draggable
- and draw a polygon with the current markers

Multiple draggable markers connected with a polygon on the map are no problem, but I can't figure out how to customize the marker to add dynamic content (like a number), so I can identify each marker.

Is there an easy way to add a dynamic number to the marker (I don't want to create an icon for each marker or implement my marker class only to add a dynamic number), or to create a custom, draggable overlay?

Comment: All the source code of the showcase is in here https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api/tree/master/gwt-maps-showcase/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/maps/testing/client/maps

Comment: @Moh but i haven't found a sample for custom markers with dynamic content. I know how to create custom markers with a different icon, but I don't know how to add something dynamic. All the samples I've found in the showcase use Google Maps markers (afaik).